# The format of linux version

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

How should I read the format for a linux distribution?

For example 2.6.18-274.3.1.el5

What is each number mean?

First the first three 2 6 18, I can find the answer here 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel#Version_numbering

What about the rest?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what you seem to be showing is the output of uname -a which contains the identification string for a kernel and generally NOT the distribution of the Linux version.

In you specific case, this is for Redhat Enterprise (or Centos) version 5 probably 32-bit.  The kernel version is 2.6.18 with sub-patch release 274.3.1.

For the more general case over different Linux distributions, I have found the performing the command:

```
 cat /etc/*release
```

and then grep-ing out for the details is far more effective.  Notice there is a wildcard, as the filenames are not the same between Linux distributions either.

However, as everything in differing Linux distributions, there is no ONE format.